# Why does Progress Bar always stuck at 99%?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written a small program for a Progress bar in python. But this program always stuck at 99%. There is always an inaccuracy of 1%. Below is my code.

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" % i)
    percent = float(i)/100
    hashes = '#' * int(percent * 50)
    spaces = '-' * (50 - len(hashes))
    sys.stdout.write("\rPercent: [{0}] {1}%".format(hashes + spaces, int(percent * 100)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

In the above program there is always an inaccuracy of 1%. If i take range as 100 and then calculate %; my progress bar stuck at 99% and if the range is 50 my progress bar stuck at 98%. can anyone please tell me if a am doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `range(100)` will output a list of `[0, 1, ..., 99]`. You need to use `range(101)` here. Cheers!